# Python array, how to select a block of columns and rows after a certain distance without loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I would like to select certain columns and rows from a big 2D array. For example, I want to select `N = 64` columns after every `D = 128` columns, if my big array were to have shape `(384,384)`, this would result to a smaller `(256, 256)` matrix, essentially because I want to remove redundant data from the big matrix.

My code looks like below, the problem is that I don't know how to avoid the explicit indexing(here 4 times in each direction, actually can be implemented as a loop with generic size) in a nice way without using loops if possible. Also in this example I start selection from 0 column, in general it can be started from arbitrary column.

```
row_mask = np.zeros(rows, dtype=bool)  # e.g. rows = 384
col_mask = np.zeros(cols, dtype=bool)  # e.g. cols = 384

N = 64
D = 128
# explicit selection of columns and rows
row_mask[0:N] = 1
row_mask[D:D + N] = 1
row_mask[D * 2:D * 2 + N] = 1
row_mask[-N:] = 1
col_mask[0:N] = 1
col_mask[D:D + N] = 1
col_mask[D * 2:D * 2 + N] = 1
col_mask[-N:] = 1

#Image of (384, 384), image of (256, 256)
image = Image[np.ix_(row_mask, col_mask)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, for this example with relatively large tiles it is way more efficient to use slicing in a for loop than to avoid the for loop by means of the much more expensive fancy indexing:

```
from scipy.misc import face
from timeit import timeit

img = face()

def fancy():
    D,N=128,64
    r_mask = np.arange(img.shape[0]) % D < N
    c_mask = np.arange(img.shape[1]) % D < N
    return img[r_mask[:, None] & c_mask].reshape(np.count_nonzero(r_mask), np.count_nonzero(c_mask),3)

def loopy():
    di,dj=64,64
    DI,DJ=128,128
    return np.block([[[img[i:i+di,j:j+dj]] for j in range(0,img.shape[1],DJ)] for i in range(0,img.shape[0],DI)])

(fancy()==loopy()).all()
# True
timeit(loopy,number=100)*10
# 0.763049490051344
timeit(fancy,number=100)*10
# 5.845791429746896
```

Comment: I did not expect that, but it makes perfect sense in hindsight. Is there a crossover point? I would imagine for sufficiently many blocks?

Comment: Thanks, though this answer has the same problem with the other answer posted by @MadPhysicist, basically missing N elements in each direction.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I would imagine there is, yes. Didn't look for it, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a totally general solution with fancy indexing using broadcasted addition and ravelling.

Let's take the one dimensional case:

```
arr = np.random.randint(10, size=973)

S = arr.shape[0]
N = 64
D = 128

# how many D-sized chunks?
nd = np.ceil(S / D)
# how many indices to chop from the end? I.e., which part of the last chunk doesn't fit in S?
nn = N - S + (nd - 1) * D

index = (np.arange(N) + D * np.arange(nd)[:, None]).ravel()[:-nn]
result = arr[index]
```

In 2D, this would look like

```
arr = np.random.randint(10, size=(1024, 768))

S = np.array(arr.shape)
N = 64
D = 128

nd = np.ceil(S / D)
nn = N - S + (nd - 1) * D

r_index = (np.arange(N) + D * np.arange(nd[0])[:, None]).ravel()[:-nn[0]]
c_index = (np.arange(N) + D * np.arange(nd[1])[:, None]).ravel()[:-nn[1]]
result = arr[np.ix_(r_index, c_index)]
```

You can extend this to N dimensions with just a little bit of broadcasting trickery, and a small list comprehension:

```
arr = np.random.randint(10, size=(128, 200, 64))

S = np.array(arr.shape)
N = 64  # Could be array with different value for each dimension
D = 128 # Same with this

nd = np.ceil(S / D)
nn = N - S + (nd - 1) * D
```

You will likely end up with a ragged array of indices for the whole thing, so it would be wise to switch to a list:

```
index = [(np.arange(N) + D * np.arange(ndx)[:, None]).ravel()[:-nnx] for ndx, nnx in zip(nd, nn)]
result = arr[np.ix_(*index)]
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I would appreciate if you can provide the generalization to the case where it doesn't start from 0.

Comment: @lorniper. You would add the offset to the index (trivial), and compute `nd` and `nn` to account for the difference (easy). It would be much simpler to use my other answer though.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to do this based on your other answers right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `np.arange(N)` on each value of [0, D, ...] and then unite it with `[-N:]` part.

```
import numpy as np

N = 64
D = 128
shape = (384, 384)
axis = 0
rows = np.union1d(
    np.arange(shape[axis] - N, shape[axis]),
    np.add.outer(np.arange(0, shape[axis], D), np.arange(N)).ravel(),
)
axis = 1
cols = np.union1d(
    np.arange(shape[axis] - N, shape[axis]),
    np.add.outer(np.arange(0, shape[axis], D), np.arange(N)).ravel(),
)
image = Image[np.ix_(rows, cols)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest method to avoid loops would be to use the modulo operator:

```
img = ...
r_mask = (np.arange(img.shape[0] % D < N)
c_mask = (np.arange(img.shape[0] % D < N)
result = img[r_mask[:, None] & c_mask].reshape(np.count_nonzero(r_mask), np.count_nonzero(c_mask)]
```

Or in your original notation:

```
result = img[np.ix_(r_mask, c_mask)]
```

Each half of the mask is an array matched with the appropriate dimension of `img` that sets the first `N` elements of each `D`-sized chunk to `True` and the rest to `False`. Broadcasting ensures that the two halves are combined into a mask with the same dimensions as `img`.

This method generalizes fairly well across arbitrary dimensions, although you will have to run a loop in that case:

```
mask = np.ones(arr.shape, dtype=bool)
dims = np.empty(arr.ndim)
for i, k in enumerate (mask.shape[::-1]):
    m = (np.arange(k) % D < N)
    mask &= np.expand_dims(m, np.arange(i))
    dims[i] = np.count_nonzero(m)
result = arr[mask].reshape(dims[::-1])
```

Comment: @lorniper. If you want to add the tail, just set `r_mask[-n:] = True`

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that each row in your table has 384 columns, you can use a for loop:

```
for row in table:
    row = row[:64] + row[192:256]
```

Comment: The title literally says "without loop"